# How to change the format of a DataGridView Column

Tags: winforms, datetime, sql-server-2008

I have a DataGridView containing 5 columns. Out of these columns, one contains date values.

It shows date in mm/dd/yyyy format, but I want it in dd/MMM/yyyy OR dd/mm/yyyy format.

In the database, the data type of the column is `smalldatetime` and I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Is this a web application or a windows forms application?

Answer (score 4):

You can try setting the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` as `dd/MMM/yyyy` for that particular column

Answer (score 1):

I'm talking about WinForms here: The question is not about changing the data *type*, but changing the *format*. Every column in a `DataGridView` does have a "format" column, so you can use any valid format string here.

The following formats the contents of the "ShipDate" column in the culture specific datetime format:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["ShipDate"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";
```